# Can we create List controller for CampaignMember

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, campaign-member

When i try to create a List Controller, i get the "List controllers are not supported for CampaignMember" error.

Does SFDC does not allow to create List Controller for Campaign Members

Comment: Considering that campaign members can be either leads or contacts, I'd be surprised if you could OOTB. You'd need to create a custom wrapper class for them that combined the two types of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have answered the question yourself already: `CampaignMember` is not a supported `SObjectType` to use in conjunction with a `StandardSetController`.

Simple page to demonstrate the compilation error:

```
<apex:page standardController="CampaignMember" recordSetVar="members" />
```

Message:

> List controllers are not supported for CampaignMember